# Rails query to select parent record only where all has_many's association are `true`

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

- Book `has_many` Pages
- Page `belongs_to` Book
- Page has a boolean attribute `read`

This way a Book id: 1 record may have:

- page 1 with `read` true
- page 2 with `read` true
- page 3 with `read` false

And then, Book id: 2 is:

- page 1 with `read` true
- page 2 with `read` true

This way only Book id: 2 must be returned from the query.

Currently I have:

```
Book.includes(:pages).where(pages: {read: true})
```

And it's returning both Book `id: 1` and `id: 2`.

How it could be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join clause won't be enough because you need to check that the `read` column value for each `page` children from a book parent isn't false.

You can explicitly add the needed filter using `where`:

```
Book.where.not(id: Page.where(read: false).select(:book_id))
```

By using `select` in `Page.where(read: false)` Rails performs a single query like:

```
SELECT "books".*
FROM "books"
WHERE "books"."id" NOT IN (
  SELECT "pages"."book_id"
  FROM "pages"
  WHERE "pages"."read" = $1
) [["read", false]]
```